# Centering UIButton in UINavigationBar Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

The `UIButton` in the `_navigationBar`does not center.

```
//Create UIButton
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Create Navigation Item
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init]; 
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(screenRect.size.width/2, 0.0f);
//Center titleView of Navigation Item and add closeButton
[navigationItem.titleView setCenter:center];
[navigationItem setTitleView:closeButton];
[_navigationBar setItems:@[navigationItem]];
```

It shows up always aligned to the right:
[image: UIButton not centered]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `titleView` of a `UINavigationItem` is already centered by default. I think the `setCenter` in you code is whats causing the problem. Try this:

```
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Create Navigation Item
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc]init]; 

[navigationItem setTitleView:closeButton];

[_navigationBar setItems:@[navigationItem]];
```

**Edit:** Your view controller should already have a navigation item for you to modify. Try this code

```
UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.navigationItem.titleView = closeButton;
```

Comment: I don't think you're accessing you're your navigation bar correctly. If this is a UIViewController you should already have a navigationItem to modify. See my edit.

Comment: I just tried this and it works perfectly... so this should work.

Comment: I dragged a UINavigationBar on to the ViewController and _navigationBar is connected to that. I tried your method but I don't think my UIViewController has a navigationItem because the navigationBar was empty.

Comment: yikes, i didn't realize you had to pin the UINavigationBar. Thanks for your help though. I'm an idiot